# AS3 Can you make a sidescroller camera?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've seen in flash sidescrollers they mostly use sidescroller by making the background move.

But if I had a background and I wanted the player to move and the camera to follow, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. The first is to put all of the background objects into a container MovieClip and move that instead of the player. This also makes other aspects of having a camera, such as zoom and rotation, relatively simple, since you can just scale and rotate the container MovieClip.

Another method is putting all background objects into an array. Every time there is movement, you loop through the array and move the objects. This requires more math and separate x/ y variables for each object, so it's not as convenient.

One thing to note is that if you're going to rotate the camera, you might experience vibration issues as your camera gets further away from the origin. To prevent this, you'll have to shift all of the objects in your container MovieClip closer to the origin when they get too far away.

If you want the camera to ease towards the player's position, you just move 1/10 (or some other fraction) of the distance to the camera's target position each frame.